# "Teach" compose that 2 composable are the same

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am wondering about some compose internals and how compose could be "taught" that one composable is the same composable as before.

Following example:

```kotlin
enum class State { S1, S2 }

@Composable 
fun MyUi(state : State){

  when (state) {
     S1 -> FancyUi("coming from s1")
     S2 -> FancyUi("coming from s2")
  }
}


@Composable
fun FancyUi(text : String) {
  // some fancy UI stuff is happening here :) 
}
```

I don't know what the right terminology is in compose world but what is happening is that the first `FancyUi("coming from s1")` is stopped (I think correct terminology is that composition is left) and the second `FancyUi("coming from s1")` is started (I think correct terminology is composition is entered).

What I would like to achieve though is "recomposition", so basically teach compose runtime somehow that both `FancyUi()` are actually the same object, just with different parameters.

I know you could achieve this with something like this (instead of the example above):

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun MyUi(state : State){

  val str = when (state) {
     S1 -> "coming from s1"
     S2 -> "coming from s2"
  }

  FancyUi(str)
}
```

Now `FancyUi()` doesn't get stopped when the `state` changes but instead does "recomposition" as expected.

But I am really just curious: getting back to the first example, can I teach somehow compose that both `FancyUi`are actually the same? I thought `key()` does the trick, but apparently, it doesn't:

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun MyUi(state : State){

  when (state) {
     S1 -> key("samekey") { FancyUi("coming from s1") }
     S2 -> key("samekey") { FancyUi("coming from s2") }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to "teach" compose that these elements are the same?